# WildFly 27.0.0.Final and Oracle driver classes are inaccessible

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, wildfly, wildfly-27

After migrating an application from WildFly 21 to WildFly 27, I am encountering the following error when deploying the application:

Oracle JDBC driver classes are inaccessible and thus, certain DDL types like ARRAY can not be used!

It's indeed strange because the driver is located in modules\system\layers\base, and when I access the WildFly administrative interface and perform a connection test for the datasource, it succeeds. The error only occurs when I deploy the application.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and could help?

Comment: How do you access the driver ?

Comment: The application access the database by datasource in wildfly. And wildfly connects to database by driver in localized in a specific folder of wildfly

Comment: Are you using the Jakarta EE 10 version of the driver?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the manifest of your deployment artifact to expose that module to your applications classpath